# Flutter Firebase Email Link Sign in not working /only short dynamic link is getting retrieved

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links

I want to add Authentication via Email Link to my flutter project. I sent the email using this code:

```
Future signInWithEmailandLink(userEmail) async{
      var _userEmail= userEmail;
     return await _auth.sendSignInLinkToEmail( 
        email: _userEmail,
         actionCodeSettings: ActionCodeSettings(
           url: "https://mydomain.page.link/authentication",
           handleCodeInApp: true,
           androidPackageName:"com.abc.def",
           androidMinimumVersion: "1",
         )     ).then((value){
       print("email sent");
     });
   }
```

To handle the dynamic link i am using following code:

```
void _handleLink() async {

    // Check if you received the link via `getInitialLink` first
    final PendingDynamicLinkData? initialLink = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
    
    if (initialLink != null) {
     
      final Uri deepLink = initialLink.link;
    
      // Example of using the dynamic link to push the user to a different screen
      _handleSignInLink(initialLink);
      print("DeepLink received! $deepLink");
    
    }
    
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink.listen(
          (pendingDynamicLinkData) {
        // Set up the `onLink` event listener next as it may be received here
        if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
    
          final Uri deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.link;
    
          // Example of using the dynamic link to push the user to a different screen
          _handleSignInLink(pendingDynamicLinkData);
          print("DeepLink received! $deepLink");
        }
      },
    );

}
```

Sending the EmailLink Email works perfectly fine. I now want to use _handleSignInLink to signIn to Firebase. FirebaseAuth.instance.isSignInWithEmailLink(emailLink) always returns false, because my emailLink (deeplink) is only "https://mydomain.page.link".

I once tried to manually copy the "full link" which was sent to my email into the code and it worked. but i am not able to retrieve the "full link" within the fluter application. Am i missing something?